# Post data from Wordpress form to phpBB

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, phpbb, forums

I'm attempting to send data from a form on Wordpress to phpBB to create a brand new thread with all the data from the form into the thread. I've put together a simple form on Wordpress which when submitted goes to a php file that I made, and placed in the phpbb directory

here is the code that i'm using

http://pastebin.com/vHQ76DHU

Each time I submit the input data I get a white screen, and no thread is created. Any idea why?

Thanks